# Asana returning "Private user" as name when getting user by ID or email

Tags: java, asana, asana-api

I have a Java application that queries a specific project in Asana for completed tasks. Afterwards, it looks up the assignee ID to get the name of the assignee. However, all of a sudden, Asana has started returning "Private user" as the name of the assignees. I use the official Java Asana library (v0.5.0). This started happening over the weekend. Last succesful query was on the 7th of April, and I started seeing the error on the 10th of April (it made no queries during the weekend)

I've tried to create a new token without any luck and also tried to create a token from another user with the same result. I suspected a bug in the Java library, but I experience the same error with Postman. Here is my GET request from Postman converted to curl:

```
curl -X GET \
https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/users/<emailorid> \
-H 'authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>' \
-H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
-H 'postman-token: 2bf9e5b4-69c8-20fc-4db7-7fe9f871a57b'
```

I assume the postman-token isn't necessary. Here is the response when I query other users (I replaced the id's and workspace names)

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": 9876,
    "email": null,
    "name": "Private User",
    "photo": null,
    "workspaces": [
      {
        "id": 4321,
        "name": "Workspace1"
      },
      {
        "id": 1234,
        "name": "Workspace2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Interestingly, querying the user from which I pull the token, gives me the expected result. So I tried to find some kinds of permission settings in Asana to no avail.

All 13 members of the workspace are "members" and not "guests". Removing the user with the token and re-inviting as member to the workspace again did not work either.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious setting. Maybe an update in the API that I missed? I appreciate any help in further troubleshooting, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't miss anything, but unfortunately we did! We had a bug that is of the sort that only shows up at the scale of our production environment, so we didn't catch it before release. We're aware of the issue and are working on getting a fix out as fast as possible. Thanks for your patience until we get our fix deployed!